# How to show Iframe in a div?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a div and a couple of frames 
I need to do I display them in the div

In fact, I have number of frames that are loaded on the page. And a pop-up with a div. I make the frames inside the div. But sometimes I need to use frames of page, but they are out of my div

```
<div id="Main" ></div>
            <iframe src="frmtest1.aspx" style="display:none"></iframe>
            <iframe src="frmtest2.aspx" style="display:none"></iframe>
                <input type="button" id="LoadTest1" />
                <input type="button" id="LoadTest2" />
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but I'm sure you've already asked this.

Answer (score 2):

If your frames are outside of the 'div' element, you have to set up some width and height of the div and use 'position:absolute' style with left and top (px) properties set to the frame to put it inside the div visually.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that you want to use the frames outside the div?

If so, just src them again where you would want them.

```
<iframe src="frmtest1.aspx" style="display:none"></iframe>
<iframe src="frmtest2.aspx" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Just copy these and lay it in another div.